# PHP/HTML printing two variables with an underscore inbetween?

Tags: php, html, string, variables

Hello StackOverflow Community,
I want to be able to echo that a file is uploaded in `upload/FirstName_LastName_FileName.ext` format. In my PHP file, I have this HTML here:

```
<td>File Stored in:</td>
<td>upload/$uploadName_$filename</td>
```

but it seems that this code returns `upload/$filename`. How can I remedy this situation? I'm very new to this so help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I was too hasty in trying to get this question answered that I didn't provide enough information. I actually could not use the PHP tags since it was going to be embedded into the message of the mail function. So I found a way by assigning a new variable `$uploadPath` to the code. The line now looks lke this:

```
   $uploadPath = "upload/" . $uploadName . "_" . $filename;
   // mail to, subject, message and its table...
   <td>File Stored in:</td>
   <td>$uploadPath</td>
```

Even still, thank you all for your quick answers! I gave the fastest the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this. Here's a few:

```
<td>upload/<?= $uploadName,'_',$filename; ?></td>

<td>upload/<?= $uploadName.'_'.$filename; ?></td>

<td>upload/<?php printf("%s_%s", $uploadName, $filename; ?></td>

<td>upload/<?= $uploadName; ?>_<?= $filename; ?></td>

<td>upload/<?= "{$uploadName}_{$filename}"; ?></td>
```

Comment: Advise about php.ini and short_tags!, ;D

Comment: Yes, *if* they are using PHP < 5.4 or plan to distribute their code. Otherwise this is fine since in PHP 5.4+ short echo tags are always on. In fact, this is default functionality in all non-deprecated versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use php tags:

```
<td>File Stored in:</td>
<td>upload/<?php echo $uploadName?>_<?php echo $filename?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<td><?php echo 'upload/' . $uploadName . '_' . $filename; ?>**strong text**</td>
```